# Build command names from composing words

Tags: expansion

I want to build commands to write the ToC of a paper. In my MWE the solution 1 works, but I do prefer the solution 2, which is not working. How can I make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ssxa}{test 1}
\newcommand{\ssxb}{test 2}


\begin{document}
% First solution 
\foreach \i in {\ssxa,\ssxb}{%
    \section{\i}
}
% Second solution (does not work)
\foreach \i in {a,b}{
    \edef\j{\expandafter\csname ssx\endcsname\i}
    \section{\j}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\j{\csname ssx\i\endcsname}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ssxa}{test 1}
\newcommand{\ssxb}{test 2}


\begin{document}
% First solution 
\foreach \i in {\ssxa,\ssxb}{%
    \section{\i}
}
% Second solution (does not work)
\foreach \i in {a,b}{
    \section{\csname ssx\i\endcsname}
}
\end{document}
```